# Block wordpress style for my plugin admin page

Tags: plugins, css, codex

I have my own style for my plugin, it works, but wordpress adds a style too, and the page is not looking very ok.
Is there any way to block wordpress style for my plugin administration page?

Comment: Style your plugin element with higher selector priority, using id maybe. Ex: `#myplugin input{}`, where wordpress might have used `input{}`. Blocking WordPress script could break other dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin stylesheets combines rules for everything: tool bar, left menu, footer and some common elements like tables and forms. You cannot disable just a part of it.

If you want to apply your own rules, use a higher specificity in your CSS rules. Normally, all plugin pages use the same wrapper element:

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <!-- page content here -->
</div>
```

You can add an `id` attribute here …

```html
<div class="wrap" id="unique_plugin_prefix">
    <!-- page content here -->
</div>
```

… and use that selector in your styleheet:

```css
#unique_plugin_prefix p 
{
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, but, for example, wp has a font, and it applies it everywhere, so i have to write in my style for every element the browser's default font. Or the same with radio inputs :(

Comment: @artur99 You _could_ use the universal selector `#unique_plugin_prefix *`. Be aware, your users might use an admin theme already to set custom fonts and dimensions. If you change too much, your plugin will break for those users.